# Can someone merge the Google Datastore tags

Tags: discussion, tag-synonym-process

As I don't have necessary rep to do it, I am asking here. As far as I know these are one and the same:

- [gae-datastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gae-datastore)
- [google-datastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-datastore)
- [google-cloud-datastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-datastore)

Comment: Also, please make `google-cloud-datastore` the canonical one.